# Motorcycle electric start issue

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting, starter

Basically I've had my bike for around 7 months now, from new. I've had this issue since getting the bike, I took it to the dealer I purchased from for my first service and told him about the issue, he told me he had fixed it and it was fine, but, obviously, it's not. I have warranty on the bike but I don't want to get rid of it and get a new one really. I want to sort it. Basically I have to kick start it 100% of the times, the electric start just acts as if the battery is dead and the dash lights flicker off and on.

Would you recommend I take it to the garage? Or go through the manufacturer's warranty and replace the whole bike? Thanks

Comment: @David That's an excellent answer to the question, and really should be posted as such, not as a comment. It's a warranty issue.

Comment: @Leliel Thanks for the encouragement. Suggestion taken.

Answer (score 4):

If the machine is still under warranty, take it back to the dealer and have them fix it. That's what the warranty is for, and it's their obligation to do so.

New vehicle warranties come from the manufacturer, not from the dealer. If multiple dealers are available to you, you might take it to another dealer rather than the one whose "fix" was unavailing.